# Can't get iptables working in VPS - state and conntrack not possible

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, vps, conntrack

I've been browsing and reading documentations all night and I can't figure out any solution...

I'm trying to get iptables working on my VPS (Debian 7).

But I can't get established connections answered. The `"-m state --state"` and also `"-m conntrack --ctstate"` both don't work.
Both result in iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

As far as I figured out, state has been outsourced from iptables and conntrack isn't installed on my system and isn't possible to be installed because I ain't got Kernel-Access to the network interfaces system.
I tried to install it from scratch but both tries (from packages and from source) failed. I changed the system to Ubuntu 14.04 for try but it didn't work either.

Is there any workaround or anything else I can do? I'm regulary using PF with OpenBSD as Firewall, so I'm not very familiar with iptables.

Here are the rules I'm adding - have I maybe forgotten something?

```
iptalbes -F
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

All rules beside the mentioned one are working well!

I found this question asked here before but there were no helpful answers or solutions.

I'm thankful for any help in advance :)

Comment: What type VPS is it? (Do uname -a and paste it)

Answer (score 0):

Is kernel module nf_conntrack exist at /lib/modules//kernel/net/netfilter/ and loaded? If exist try:

```
modprobe nf_conntrack
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't exist. Conntrack doesn't seem to be an option here.

Comment: Are you running on OpenVZ? If yes, try to install linux-image deb packet same version as your running kernel and then try to load module, if it doesn't help then you should contact your provider to enable iptables.

Comment: Hey Maxiko, sadly I'm not running on OpenVZ. This would've made it much easier....
Provider has been contacted but hasn't responded yet...

Comment: Anyway, try to install linux-image deb packet same version as your running kernel.

Comment: I did so, conntrack and state still not working.
Should I try installing conntrack by hand now again or isn't it worth the try?